# Xtend: Generate Switch Case

Tags: jvm, xtext, xtend

I need to generate switch case inside a method. Something like this:

```
    switch(phr){
    case PENDING_CONFIRMATION:
        phrResource.add(new ExtendedLink(linkTo(
                methodOn(PHRController.class).rejectPhr(phr.getId()))
                .toString(), "rejectPHR_Update", "DELETE"));
```

How to do this in Xtend-JVM?

Comment: what is your exact question, which statements work in xtend as well. so can you give more context

Comment: I have to generate a switch statement for a list of enums. How to write a code in JVM to automatically generate switch statement

Comment: hi i have still no clue what you are talking about? jvmModelInferrer? Active Annotation? in both you ususally dont sythesize single expressions

Comment: I am talking about JVMModelInferrrer. I solved this.